# Mediawiki: BlogPage extension not showing up in Special:Version

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I have installed the **BlogPage** extension & other required extensions like **Comments, SocialProfile and Votes** in mediawiki and changed Localsettings.php like this:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/SocialProfile/SocialProfile.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Comments/Comment.php";
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['commentlinks'] = true;
require_once "$IP/extensions/VoteNY/VoteNY.php";
$wgVoteDirectory = "$IP/extensions/VoteNY";
require_once "$IP/extensions/BlogPage/BlogPage.php";
```

& updated wiki after that. In my **Special:Version** page all the extensions other than **BlogPage** are listed.Why is that? As the extension page says I navigated to **Special:CreateBlogPost** and got this **error:**
**"No such special page.You have requested an invalid special page."**
Please help me solve this problem.

**Wiki Details**
MediaWiki   1.23.2
PHP 5.3.3 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.1.73

Answer (score 2):

The installation instructions are [wrong; I’ve fixed them](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Extension%3ABlogPage&diff=1336457&oldid=1196879).

Replace this line…

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/BlogPage/BlogPage.php";
```

… with this line:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/BlogPage/Blog.php";
```